# Переименовать изображение при загрузке на сервер через uniqid

Tags: php, fileupload

Загружаю изображение через форму таким образом

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"rentgen/userphotos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

$location="rentgen/userphotos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как динамически переименовать изображение ? читал что есть функция uniqid как можно использовать эту функцию в данном коде ?

Comment: `$name = uniqid().'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file()` функция в качестве второго аргумента принимает путь, по которому необходимо переместить файл.В самом конце пути указывается имя файла.В вашем случае его и надо изменить.

**Решение с использованием функции [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php):**

> Внимание: Эта функция пытается создать уникальный идентификатор, но не
>   дает 100% гарантии уникальности.

```
$original_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

//Получить расширение файла
$extension = pathinfo($original_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Придумать новое имя файла с расширением загружаемого файла
$new_name = uniqid().'.'.$extension;

//и загружаем уже с измененным именем
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"rentgen/userphotos/" . $new_name);
```

[Пример move_uploaded_file.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php#refsect1-function.move-uploaded-file-examples)

Comment: Внимание

Эта функция не гарантирует получения уникального значения. Большинство операционных систем синхронизирует время с NTP, либо его аналогами, так что системное время постоянно меняется. Следовательно возможна ситуация, когда эта функция вернет неуникальный идентификатор для процесса/потока. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @Visman `Подскажите пожалуйста как динамически переименовать изображение ? читал что есть функция uniqid как можно использовать эту функцию в данном коде ?` Отвечал на этот вопрос

Comment: Так можно ответить правильно, даже отвечая на этот вопрос :Р

Comment: @Visman читайте вопрос повнимательней.автор хотел использовать функцию uniqid() и не задавался вопросом об уникальности.

Comment: @Visman Цитирую вопрос для вас `Переименовать изображение при загрузке на сервер через uniqid`.

Comment: Цитируйте - не цитируйте, но с использованием вашего решения может произойти ситуация, когда новый файл затрет старый файл.

Comment: @Visman Тут отвечают на конкретные вопросы а не статьи пишут.Возникнет такая ситуация или сам разберётся или напишет новый вопрос.В этом СО 90% ответов на конкретные вопросы.Но чтоб не происходили спекуляции возле моих ответов добавлю ссылку в ответ

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши ответы. Да действительно я в курсе что нет 100 процентной гарантии что функция генерирует уникальные названия. Но , скрипт будет использоваться в локальной сети где максимум 15-20 компов. Исходя из этого что время во всех компах одинкаовые можно в каком то смысле доверять этой функции.  Vanya Avchyan  прав я конкретно спрашивал про то как в моём коде использовать эту функцию , иными словами "что куда" писать чтоб названия имейдждей были разными. Буду иметь ввиду конечно же ! Visman,тоже очень часто помогает мне здесь. Так что от души всем спасибо !)

Comment: @AlexStassov Всегда пожалуйста  :). Я сам часто пользовался этой функцией.В принципе можно микросекунды вместо нее.